# R: Removing Whitespace + Delimiter

Tags: r, delimiter, strsplit

I'm fairly new to the R language. So I have this vector containing the following:

```
> head(sampleVector)

[1] "| txt01 |   100 |         200 |       123.456 |           0.12345 |"
[2] "| txt02 |   300 |         400 |       789.012 |           0.06789 |"
```

I want to extract the lines and break each into separate pieces, with a data value per piece.
I want to get a list `resultList`that eventually would print out the following:

```
> head(resultList)`

[[1]]`  
[1] ""   "txt01"    "100"       "200"     "123.456"        "0.12345" 

[[2]]`  
[1] ""   "txt02"    "300"       "400"     "789.012"        "0.06789"
```

I am struggling with the `strsplit()` notation and I have tried and got the following code so far:

```
resultList  <- strsplit(sampleVector,"\\s+[|] | [|]\\s+ | [\\s+]")`          
#would give me the following output`

# [[1]]`    
# [1] "| txt01"    "100"       "200"     "123.456"        "0.12345 |"
```

Anyway I can get the output the one `strsplit` call? I am guessing my notation to distinguish the delimiter + whitespace is wrong. Any help on this would be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another `strsplit` option which I nearly missed:

```
strsplit(test,"[| ]+")
#[[1]]
#[1] ""        "txt01"   "100"     "200"     "123.456" "0.12345"
# 
#[[2]]
#[1] ""        "txt02"   "300"     "400"     "789.012" "0.06789"
```

...and my original answer because `regmatches` is my favourite function of late:

```
regmatches(test,gregexpr("[^| ]+",test))
#[[1]]
#[1] "txt01"   "100"     "200"     "123.456" "0.12345"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "txt02"   "300"     "400"     "789.012" "0.06789"
```

To break it down as requested:

`[| ]+` is a regex searching for single or repeated instances `+` of a space   or a pipe  `|`
`[^| ]+` is a regex searching for single or repeated instances `+` of any character not `^` a space   or a pipe  `|`
`gregexpr` finds all the instances of this pattern and returns the start locations and length of the matching patterns.
`regmatches` extracts all the patterns from `test` that are matched by `gregexpr`

Comment: Oh, sure.  Come with all that fancy stuff.

Comment: @RichardScriven - I do like to swoop in with an alternative ;-)

Comment: Did you see my `scan` alternative?  Thinking outside the box

Comment: @RichardScriven - `scan` is neat - you could potentially concoct something with `read.table` too.

Comment: I think OP wants to capture the blanks as well

Comment: Do you care to elaborate on this interesting looking entity? :)

Comment: That `strsplit` solution is money in the bank. @MagnumOpus - I think you should accept this answer instead

Comment: Okay so any symbols in the brackets `[| ]` are the symbols we are putting in the current context. What does the `+` notation after the square brackets indicate?

Comment: @MagnumOpus - `+` represents repeats of whatever text comes before it.

Comment: Okay. I will study and look into regex notations more. @thelatemail Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way.  This first removes the `|` from the vector with `gsub`. Then it uses `strsplit` on the spaces (or any number of spaces). Probably a bit easier that way.

```
strsplit(gsub("|", "", sampleVector, fixed=TRUE), "\\s+")
# [[1]]
# [1] ""        "txt01"   "100"     "200"     "123.456" "0.12345"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] ""        "txt02"   "300"     "400"     "789.012" "0.06789"
```

Here's an interesting alternative using `scan` that might be useful, and will probably be quite fast.

```
lapply(sampleVector, function(y) {
    s <- scan(text = y, what = character(), sep = "|", quiet = TRUE)
    (g <- gsub("\\s+", "", s))[-length(g)]
})
# [[1]]
# [1] ""        "txt01"   "100"     "200"     "123.456" "0.12345"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] ""        "txt02"   "300"     "400"     "789.012" "0.06789"
```

Comment: Wow thanks mate. I was looking into `gsub` but I didn't think of putting it within the `strsplit` function. Thanks. Will accept as answer (in around 6 minutes when SO allows me too) ahahahah thanks again for the help P.S. I wish i can upvote this ahahhaha

Comment: No worries.  I really like these types of problems :).  Also, not sure if you want to keep the first `""` element. It can be removed easily with `lapply(resultList, "[", -1)`

Comment: ahahahahha i'm getting the hang of it. I am unfamiliar with the notations like similar to `\\s`. Thanks again. Wish of luck for the SF Giants :)

Comment: Ah I would need it when I do my matrix manipulations later on but I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

May try strsplit first and the gsub:

```
sapply(strsplit(xx, '\\|'), function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x))
     [,1]     
[1,] ""       
[2,] "txt01"  
[3,] "100"    
[4,] "200"    
[5,] "123.456"
[6,] "0.12345"
```

Comment: i wanted to return a list with each list component containing the split characters. but thanks anyway!